# How to do a line break in JSON inside a TableLayout?

Tags: javascript, json, android-studio

First of all, have a good day, My question is the following, I have a Json that I show in a **TableLayout**. The data that I have in my **JSON** are: **Student ID, Name, Age and Extra**. When displaying it, the data is displayed in a single Row (List), at the moment I want to be a line break, it does not detect the "\ n" but instead gives me a spacing.

I want to know how I can make a line break in the row or in the ArrayJson or in another way but to help me, I would really appreciate it. in this case show me as follows:

**ID ALUMNO          NOMBRE              EDAD     EXTRA**

```
   1          Fernanda Hernandez        20        1

   2          Daniel Gutierrez          21        2

   3          Valeria Rios              22        3
```

The code I have is:

```
for(int  =0; i<jsonArray.lenght();i++{

JSONObject jsObt = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

idAlumno = jsObt.getString("idAlumno");
Nombre = jsObt.getString("Nombre");
Edad = jsObt.getString("Edad");
Extra = jsObt.getString("Extra");

textview = new TextView(getAplicationContext());
textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
textview.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
textview.setText(idAlumno);

row.addView(textview);

textview2 = new TextView(getAplicationContext());
textview2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
textview2.setPadding(225, 25, 25, 25);
textview2.setText(Nombre);

row.addView(textview2);

textview3 = new TextView(getAplicationContext());
textview3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
textview3.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
textview3.setText(Edad);

row.addView(textview3);

textview4 = new TextView(getAplicationContext());
textview4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
textview4.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25);
textview4.setText(Extra);

row.addView(textview4);

}

tablelayout.addView(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `padding` to the `TableRow` element.

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="2dip" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, how do I command to call the **View** in .java?